# Java + Spring - How to validate an enum

Tags: java, spring, enums, annotations, constraints

Question is straightforward - how do you validate an enum?

I tried `@NotNull`, `@NotBlank`, `@NotEmpty`, `@Size`, and `@Min` + `@Max`.

Every one I try, it says

> The annotation @_____ is disallowed for this location

**Which annotation should I use????**

Variable:

```
private static enum GearTeethType{OUTERTEETH, INNERTEETH, NOTEETH}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not variable that you are showing, but the enum declaration. Try to declare variable as `private GearTeethType gearTeethType;` and annotate it.